# Do not focus on search box on touch of jQuery chosen dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I am using jQuery chosen in my website. On touch of the dropdown on iPad the keyboard comes up, this is because the search field in the dropdown gets focussed. But I do not want the search field to be focussed on touch of the dropdown. The keyboard should only appear on touch of the search field.

Please help me to accomplish the above.

Regards,

Neha